# Ethernet controller I219-LM not claimed by driver e1000e

Tags: linux, rhel, ethernet, oracle-linux

Today I received a brand new Dell OptiPlex 7080 and I installed Oracle Linux 7 on it. The machine has an external wireless antenna and an ethernet port. The wireless antenna works, but the ethernet port does not work.

When I run `lshw -class network` I get the following output which shows that the ethernet controller is UNCLAIMED:

```
  *-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: e0:d4:64:cf:03:64
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.17-2036.103.3.el7uek.x86_64 firmware=50.3e391d3e.0 ip=192.168.178.48 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:91234000-91237fff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:91200000-9121ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:f5:ae:a3
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:f5:ae:a3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

If I run `lspci -v` I see the Wi-Fi controller and the Ethernet controller. The former has a kernel module (in use), the latter has nothing:

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4070
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at 91234000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM
    Subsystem: Dell Device 09a4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 91200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
```

The internet suggested that e1000e is the driver for this Ethernet I219-LM controller. If I run `lsmod | grep e1000e` this shows no results. I can load the driver with `modprobe e1000e` after which it shows up in `lsmod`, but the Network Settings GUI does not allow me to select a wired connection. I also do not see any errors in `dmesg | grep e1000e`; only the copyright notice.

I tried to run a live version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from a USB, and Ubuntu did recognize my Ethernet controller, so I do not think this is a hardware issue.

What would be the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by following the steps in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094806) answer:

- Download e1000e version 3.8.4 from [Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-).
- Extract the tar
- `cd src`
- `sudo make install`
- Reboot

Comment: Tested but not working on with same problem on Linux Mint 20.2.

Comment: Tried this on Ubuntu 21.10 and this does not work. I believe it is because I'm using kernel 5.x and this driver (according to Intel in the link in this answer) is compatible with kernel 2.4, 2.6.x, and 3.x

Comment: @smoothgrips You may be right. Even on Ubuntu 16.04, this driver has massive packet loss, possibly because the kernel is 4.x

Comment: Another data point: I'm having the same problem using RHEL7 (kernel 3.10) on a Dell Latitude 5430.  Couldn't see the network adapter (I219) at all at first.  Building and installing version 3.8.4 of the e1000e driver helps a lot, in that I can now see the interface, and bring it up and talk over it.  But I'm getting ~30% packet loss. :-(